# Set initial scroll position of the collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have tried many solutions but none of them work. The question is simple — how to scroll down during `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` without visual(jump) effect?

What I have now:

```
public override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if (!self.layoutFlag) {

        if let lastCell: IndexPath = self.lastCellIndexPath {
            self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: lastCell, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
            self.layoutFlag = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try set `animated` to `false`?

Comment: @JuicyFruit, yes, it is even visually worse.

Comment: well, you can set `collection view` hidden, set `alpha` to 0, then after `scrolltoitem` show it, animating its `alpha`

Comment: Not sure but check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617724-targetcontentoffsetforproposedco?language=objc) if it works.

Answer (score 9):

I found only one way to set initial scroll position:

call my scroll function in [viewDidLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews)

```
var isScrolled = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if !isScrolled && levelCollectionView.visibleCells.count > 0 {
        isScrolled = true
        // scroll
    }
}
```

it doesn't look as correct answer but it works

Comment: This is great, it works, but was too hacky for me, so I made a subclass. See other answers here somewhere

Answer (score 7):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Just wrap `scrollToItem` within an async block. It works perfectly, no visual transition and easy to apply.

How it worked I can only guess. Synchronously scroll  the collection view in viewDidLoad will not do because it hasn't been laid out yet. Commit scroll in an async block adds this action to the next runloop task, when next runloop executes, which is exactly when ui will be drawn, the scroll executes right after, and displayed in the same frame.

All a above is just a guess, anyone has any idea I'd be glad to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Checked in a test project, works in `viewWillAppear`. I've added 3 screens, 1-st is clean, second contains collectionView and the last one is empty.

Implementation of the second screen is below (viewWillAppear triggers UIScrollView extension method and scrolls content):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        collectionView.scrollToBottom(animated: false)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,
                          UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 200
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's an `extension` for scrolling content:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
        setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -contentInset.top),
                         animated: animated)
    }

    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
        setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                     animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Try to make a `new clean` project and play with it.

Comment: @danilabagroff well, if it works in a test project (its not playground) then you already have a solution that should work. You can slowly exclude some functionality from your original project, investigate what causes the glitch and find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

I found this solution for myself

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    let maxYPosition = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
    let collectionViewHeight = collectionView.bounds.height
    
    return CGPoint(x: 0, y: maxYPosition - collectionViewHeight)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the scroll to index path call to the `viewDidAppear(_:)` method and have the `animated` parameter set to `false`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if !self.layoutFlag {
        if let lastCell: IndexPath = self.lastCellIndexPath {
            self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: lastCell, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: false)
            self.layoutFlag = true
        }
    }
}
```

The collection view should be scrolled to the bottom before the view is shown to the user, thus no "jump".

Comment: Idk where the downvotes come from, but this works for me.